# Animate the fall of item WPF

Tags: wpf, animation

Could you please help me  to implement in my WPF Application the fall of an image (png) from the outside (from the top) of my window. And finally it should be located in a certain point of the window. Sry for English btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this as it is :

```
<Window ...
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window15" Height="300" Width="300">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Sb1">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Btn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" To="100" >
                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    <BounceEase Bounces="2" EasingMode="EaseOut" 
                                 Bounciness="2" />
                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Sb1}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>

    <Canvas Background="AliceBlue">
        <Button x:Name="Btn" Canvas.Top="-60" Canvas.Left="150"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Change `To` property accordingly.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!